# Is there a Generic python library to consume REST based services?

Tags: python, rest

Ok.  I want to consume REST based services.

I'd like to use python. In fact, I am going to use python.

The way I'd like to use it is from the command line/ipython, to try out different REST services, with intention of formally coding it later. ( my usage of the REST service *not* the generic api thing )

I'm looking for a pretty generic, fully featured REST client/API in python.  Not bare bones, but plush, nice to use.  There are tons of them out there, but I'd kind of like to settle on one and master it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:  This is one:

https://github.com/benoitc/restkit

EDIT: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests  is exactly it.

EDIT: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/siesta  is just as perfect!

Comment: I'm sad to see your question was closed this way, as I think it's useful. Also I notice you answered it yourself much better than the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: Thx a lot for this question and your own answers. Helped me a lot when looking for good Python REST clients.

Comment: Slumber is a really good REST client library: http://slumber.in/

Comment: Maybe this question, possibly with answers, should be moved to Software Recommendations where it would be on topic and could be live.

Comment: Finch is another one https://github.com/jaimegildesagredo/finch

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with having a "plush" REST client library is that REST itself isn't that well-defined. REST, in and of itself, just means that you want to use HTTP standards whenever possible, but other than that, the field is wide open.

Is the data encoded with JSON? What are the URL schemes and what do they mean?

Since REST basically just means HTTP, your best bet is httplib, but I wouldn't describe it as plush.

Answer (score 4):

I've mostly used just [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2) or [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). I haven't really found a use for a general purpose REST client.

Answer (score 2):

Something like a generic REST library is hardly possible since each REST interface is different. Whith [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) there has been an attempt to establish a WSDL-lik interface description language for RESTful services. Using such a description a generic client would be possible but no one seems to care about WADL. And everyone seems fine with that.