# generic bridge framework for Python

Tags: python, api, bridge

Is there a Python framework that makes it easy to build a bridge to any API?

A "bridge" in this context meaning simply: Some website or service exposes a JSON API. I want to get well-defined Python objects from the API instead of JSON.

It seems to me that the "bridge" pattern consists of some pretty simple components:

- request / authentication handling
- model definitions that match the API endpoints
- translation from JSON into models

Rather than re-creating this pattern from scratch for every API that I want to make a bridge to, it seems like it would be smart to just have a generic "bridge" framework that simply required model definitions and some customization for the API you wanted to use. Sort of like Django, but for building bridge libraries instead of web apps.

Anybody know of anything like that out there?

Comment: I like the idea, so I'm upvoting you, but sadly this question will *probably* be closed as off-topic nonetheless

Comment: Hope it doesn't get closed. I think "what tool do I use for x" is a pretty valid question for SO, and it hasn't been asked before as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, here's why it'll be closed: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: hah. okay good point. well I still hope it doesn't get closed.

Comment: @SteveJessop: yup ```jsonpickle``` can handle that with minimal customization, you would just need some model definition to load the dict into and a lightweight language for attribute translation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Generic python library to consume REST based services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355997/is-there-a-generic-python-library-to-consume-rest-based-services)

Comment: Now I voted to close my own question :)

Comment: Voted to close. For one, it's asking for a tool, but more importantly, it's looking for a tool that works for "any API". Unlike in the SOAP world, there isn't standardization on these APIs except for the fact that you access them over HTTP. Unless that changes, I'd recommend sticking to something like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and some of the auth plugins, which in most cases can be used to create a pretty quick wrapper against most APIs.

Comment: @mark-hildreth you can't be more wrong! There's a real specification around REST APIs that make it generic enough for being used as a RPC! Look at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) page! (though I still voted to close that question as being a duplicate of an offtopic question ;-) )

Comment: @zmo: I said nothing about REST: I talked about "APIs" in general. Each API works differently, and in many cases don't even practice REST. Therefore, one utopian library to rule them all is a problematic proposition (a "toolkit" like requests, perhaps). Also, please realize that "REST" is not a _standard_ nor a _specification_. There is no RFC for "REST". It's an architectural style. You cannot create a library to communicate with a REST API, because REST is just a series of constraints that you use to make your actual application. A true "REST" application does not even need to use HTTP.

Comment: well, not commenting more on that topic, because that's exactly why that kind of question is off-topic. Opinion-biased etc… though you're right that I misread the OP's question, he did indeed ask for **any** API, and not for RESTful API. Sometimes the brain invents stuff that just isn't there. And thus, I do agree with your comment, but I disagree with the fact REST is not specified. *N.B.*: None of the RFC are **actually** specifications, they just are proposals of guidelines that may or may not be followed by implementers! (unlike ISO/ANSI etc…). I'm now considering that post on hold ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [restkit](https://github.com/benoitc/restkit) which will do the job as you expect.

but as the duplicate I showed off states, you can find as well:

- [siesta](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/siesta)
- or build your own easily with [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) and python's included json parser.